# Wanting to match a phrase with preg_replace that is case insensitive

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to check for the phrase "company billing" and for it to be case insensitive for the entire phrase (i.e., should pick up "Company Billing", "company billing", "CoMpAny BillING", etc).

My code here doesn't seem to want to pick it up. I'm sure I have some incorrect regex in there:

```
if (preg_match("/company billing\b/i", $post['message']) !== false) {
  $post['message'] = preg_replace('/billing\b/i', 'Company Billing', $post['message']);
}
```

Comment: What is your input string? and what result do you have?

Comment: Why are you doing the match against `$string`, but the replace against `$post['messsage']`? And shouldn't that be `$_POST` instead of `$post`?

Comment: I forgot to put it in the $post['message'] part.

Comment: This is what I have now. It seems to not be looking for the whole phrase in its entirety, but just the first word "company". That alone triggers it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your RegEx needs to grow more complicated than this later on, [str_ireplace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) seems better here.  No need for the conditional either, since if "company billing" in any form isn't found in the string, no changes will be made:

```
$post['message'] = str_ireplace("company billing", "Company Billing", $post['message']);
```

Comment: This is what I have now. However, it seems to ignore the "billing" part of the phrase, instead of looking for the WHOLE phrase "company billing"

Comment: It may just be another small typo, but this:  $post['message'] = preg_replace('/billing\b/i', 'Company Billing', $post['message']); might need to be changed to:  $post['message'] = preg_replace('/company billing\b/i', 'Company Billing', $post['message']);  ... The former would replace "Company Billing" with "Company Company Billing".  The latter would replace it with just "Company Billing"

Answer (score 0):

This should be good enough:

```
if (preg_match("/\bcompany billing\b/i", $string)) {
   // handle match success case
}
else {
   // handle match failure case
}
```

[**`preg_match`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) **returns 0 if match fails**

**It returns FALSE only if an error occurrs.**

Comment: @Barmar Ok got it, anyway I have completed it with my comments to show where to put failure case and where to put success code.

Comment: He's most likely not interested in doing anything in the failure case.

Comment: @Barmar: not a problem I just want to make it clear for anybody reading it and an empty else block won't hurt anything :P